# Is this possible with contact form 7? - Have 2 different size texts as a title (label) with CSS?

Tags: css, contact-form-7

Using Contact form 7, Is it possible to have my checkbox label (the title) in 2 different size texts with CSS?

Currently, it is: What You Are Interests? (select all that apply.)
font-size: 14px

I want to have is the following:

What You Are Interests? - as Size 14px

(select all that apply.) - as Size 10px

Check out the picture please See Picture [Picture Is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW6So.png)

the CSS Code I'm currently using for the contact form 7 checkbox

```
.wpcf7-form label {
  color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
        
}

/* custom checkbox styling for contact form 7 checkbox */
span.wpcf7-list-item {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
}
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-list-item {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.wpcf7-checkbox label {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
/*position: relative;*/
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox] + span {
    
/* border: 3px solid red; */
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox] + span:before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 0;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
border: 1px solid white;
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox] + span:after {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: "\2713";
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
visibility: hidden;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {
background: transparent;
}
.wpcf7-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:after {
visibility: visible;
}
.wpcf7-list-item-label {
margin-left: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

[text* First-Name placeholder "First Name"]

```
[text* Last-Name placeholder "Last Name"]

[email* your-email placeholder "Email"]

[tel* tel-phone placeholder "Phone Number"]

[text* text-DOB placeholder "Date Of Birth (DD-MM-YYY)"]

[text* text-city placeholder "City / Town"]

[textarea* textarea-128 placeholder "Hello Learn To Fly USA, My current Experience level is ...., Hours many hours flown ...., I have Licenses or Qualifications etc"]

<label> What You Are Interests? (select all that apply.)
[checkbox* Q2Whatareyourinterests use_label_element "Training" "Employment" "Travel"]

<label> When Are You Ready?
[checkbox* Q3Whenareyouready use_label_element "As Soon As Possible" "Within 1 to 2 years" "Undecided"]

[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: What does your form code look like?

Comment: Ive attached it now in the description. I tried to change this already but didn't work, or maybe I did it wrong. @HowardE

Comment: Your label tag isn't closed `</label>`, and you can have a class on label `<label class="my-label">` and then add css for it.

Comment: oh ok ... So its HTML? What code do I need to write? Sorry, I'm a beginner. @HowardE